# Как обойти ошибку неправильного закрытия тега при парсинге сайта c помощью BS4?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautiful-soup, bs4

BS4 не видит закрытие html тега `<dt>` из-за этого ломается продолжение чтения самого блока. 
Вот DOM страницы:

```
<div class="movie-page-block__summary">
                    <dl>
                                                    <dt name="year">Рік</dd>
                            <dd>2019</dd>

                                                    <dt name="country">Країна</dt>
                            <dd>Австралія, США</dd>

                                                    <dt name="duplication_lang">Мова</dt>
                            <dd>українська (дубльований)</dd>

                                                    <dt name="genre">Жанр</dt>
                            <dd>пригоди, сімейний, фантастика</dd>

                                                    <dt name="in_stars">У головних ролях</dt>
                            <dd>Ізабела Монер, Бенісіо Дель Торо, Майкл Пенья, Єва Лонгорія, К’Оріанка Кілчер</dd>

                                                    <dt name="director">Режисер</dt>
                            <dd>Джеймс Бобін</dd>

                                                    <dt name="writters">Сценарій</dt>
                            <dd>Кріс Гіффорд, Даніель Санчез, Ніколас Столлер</dd>

                                                    <dt name="rental_date">Прокат</dt>
                            <dd>
                                                                    <span>З 15 серпня 2019                                    </span>

                                                                        <span>до 11 вересня 2019                                    </span>
                                                                    </dd>



                                                                                                                                                <dt name="discounts">Знижки                                                <?//= implode(', ', $technologesNameArr) ?> </dt>
                                                                                    <dd>
                                        <span>
                                            З 22 серпня 2019                                        </span>


                                                    <dt name="duration">Тривалість</dt>
                        <dd>102 хв.</dd>

                                                    <dt name="age_limit">Вікові обмеження</dt>
                            <dd>0+</dd>

                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
```

А это загруженая страница: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код который я использую:

```
from urllib.request import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

import http.client

http.client._MAXHEADERS = 1000

def parse_genre_and_time_duration_planeta(host, link):
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/5.0'}
    req = Request(link,headers=hdr)
    page = urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")
    for element in soup.findAll("div", class_="movie-page-block__summary"):
        print(element)

parse_genre_and_time_duration_planeta("https://planetakino.ua", "https://planetakino.ua/movies/dora-and-the-lost-city-of-gold/#today")
```

Вот что из-за этого получается:

```
(venv) chesterfield@chesterfield:~/dev/app_test_2/parse$ python parse_planeta.py 
<div class="movie-page-block__summary">
<dl>
<dt name="year">Рік</dt></dl></div>
```

Мне нужно вытащить информацию о жанре и времени этого фильма. Подскажите куда нужно копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не там ищете.
Тег  который вы находите, закрывается раньше чем находится нужная вам информация.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теги которые вы ищите лежат в корне. Получить можно так, отличить один от другого в данном случае можно только по порядковому номеру.

```
from urllib.request import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import http.client

http.client._MAXHEADERS = 1000

def parse_genre_and_time_duration_planeta(link):
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/5.0'}
    req = Request(link,headers=hdr)
    page = urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "html.parser")

    for element in soup.find_all("dd"):
        print(element)



parse_genre_and_time_duration_planeta("https://planetakino.ua/movies/dora-and-the-lost-city-of-gold/#today")
```

Comment: Это работает, спасибо. Есть вопрос чтобы полностью разобраться, на скриншоте выше (моем) видно что тэг не закрываеться так, как на фашем скриншоте. С чем это связано?

Comment: Если честно, я впервые сегодня парсил сайт(:
Возможно браузер скрывает часть тегов или есть проблема в самой библиотеке.
На моём скриншоте я сохранил весь вывод метода BeautifulSoup() в текстовый файл и просто прочитал что получилось. 

Получается либо браузер отображает не все теги, либо есть баг в библиотеке bs4.

Можете попробовать другую библиотеку, просто для проверки. Точнее не могу подсказать, удачи!